# Python Regex And encode

Tags: python, utf-8

I Am trying to find and print all the Phone numbers in this file. But the file got a lot of unreadable text.
The file looks like this but then really big:
e

How Can I decode this and find all the numbers? I now have the following code:

```
import glob
import re

path = "C:\\Users\\Joey\\Downloads\\db_sdcard\\mysql\\ibdata1"
files= glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
        with open(name, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                print line
                match = re.search(r'(/b/d{2}-/d{8}/b)', line)
                if match:
                    found = match.group()
                    print found
```

When I run my script i get the following output:

```
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

Where do I have to put the `.decode('utf8')` And is my code for the rest good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following to find your numbers:

```
re.findall("\d{2}-\d{8}", line)
```

It creates a list of all of the matching substrings that fit the format `xx-xxxxxxxx`, where `x` is a digit.

---

When using the last line from your question as an example:

```
>>> line = '   P t\xe2\x82\xac         \xc5\x92  \xc3\x98p\xe2\x82\xac Q~\xc3\x80t\xc3\xb406-23423230xx06-34893646xx secure_encryptedsecure_encrypted\xe2\x82\xac  -\xe2\x82\xac  -\xe2\x82\xac  \n'
>>> re.findall("\d{2}-\d{8}", line)
['06-23423230', '06-34893646']
```

---

Here it is in the full statement:

```
for name in files:
    with open(name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            matches = re.findall("\d{2}-\d{8}", line)
            for mt in matches:
                print mt
```

This will `print` each match on separate lines.

---

You could even `findall` the matches in the whole file at once:

```
for name in files:
    with open(name, 'r') as f:
        matches = re.findall("\d{2}-\d{8}", f.read())
        for mt in matches:
            print mt
```

Comment: Hey Tnx for taking the time to help me. But when I run your script it doenst print anything

Comment: Did you substitute it into your existing code, or run it as-is? @joey

Comment: Yes, When I try to print matches I only get [] So I dont think he finds anything

Comment: The matches are `['06-23423230', '06-34893646']` for the last line. I use that to say, this *does* work, but I'm not sure how you are testing it. @joey

Comment: I am just running the script on the file. Where the first output is from

Comment: What files is the `glob` matching? If `C:/Users/Joey/Downloads/db_sdcard/mysql/ibdata1` is the file, you don't need the `glob`. @joey

Comment: Oh oke tnx for the tip. I am trying at the moment:path = "C:\\Users\\Joey\\Downloads\\db_sdcard\\mysql\\ibdata1"
with open(path, 'r') as f: But It stil prints 3x []

Comment: Try using [this code](http://txt.do/5xlho). It has revisions to your filepath as well as regex. @joey

Comment: It doenst print anything. It just does nothing like there are no matches:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96741/discussion-between-zach-gates-and-joey).